# Objective C - FB API "Don't Allow" permission callback

Tags: objective-c, facebook-graph-api

Trying to integrate FB to my app.
I see that there is fbDidLogin and fbDidNotLogin in the FBLoginDialogDelegate.

Is there also a delegate that tell is the user allow or disallow the app after login?

Thanks,
Tee